# Internet Explorer is not showing CSS at all

Tags: css, validation, internet-explorer-8

I have gone over the entire file including validating and sniffing out missing or out-of-place characters.

I have also removed all but a couple lines of the CSS file and tried this as well.

Internet Explorer is simply not showing CSS while FF, Chrome, and Safari all have no issues.

Anybody know of a setting in IE that may have been changed or a possible schema I am missing/using that could cause this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

            <head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
            <meta http-equiv="content-LANGUAGE" content="EN"/>
            <meta name="ROBOTS" content="ALL"/>
            <meta name="revisit-after" content="14 days"/>
            <meta name="resource-type" content="document"/>
            <meta name="distribution" content="Global"/>
            <meta name="rating" content="General"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.****************.css" />
            <script .......
            </head>
```

Comment: This would do it: `<!--[if !IE ]><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->` But seriously, we need more information to answer that.

Comment: code would help - are you using any IE if statements? maybe the CSS got caught in between?  Quirks mode comes to mind as well but it's hard to say without code.

Comment: Hmm I didnt want to post a direct link because I havent done enough security on it yet. Is there anythign specific I should post? Like the css file in whole or in part? Thanks

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with you putting a HEAD inside of a HEAD... IE may be handling that error incorrectly, and nuking your LINK tag as a result.

Comment: @Magic Lasso You are going to need to provide a little more information for us to be able to solve this problem. A minimal example which is complete enough to actually demonstrate the problem would help. Also, pay attention to how StackOverflow formatting works; in order to post code (including HTML), indent every line at least 4 spaces (you can do this manually, or by selecting all of your code and pressing the `{}` button to do it automatically). Please read the "How to format" section that appears on the right when you edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's the fact that you have an extra `<head>` tag within your `<head>` tag that's confusing IE?

```
<head>
<!-- snip other stuff ... -->
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.**************.css" />
```

If removing that doesn't work, then I would recommend trying to produce a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. Start by removing all of the content, except for an example to show that the style isn't being applied. Then remove more and more of your headers and code, until you find a small example in which the problem is still present, but it has nothing other than the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem. The process of doing that might help you to find your own problem; but if not, then you can post a complete example here, by editing your question, and we can give better advice based on actual code that demonstrates the problem, as opposed to an incomplete excerpt that doesn't contain enough information to determine what's wrong. Remember to post both the HTML and CSS for your example.

Comment: Lol I missed that one. That still didnt fix it though but thanks for catching it.

Comment: @Magic Lasso See my edit to my answer, describing how you can provide us with more information to be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Found the error. Had a line break '/n' using quotations in a string using apostrophes. For some reason it wasnt showing up when I viewed the file through IE. But your process worked to narrow down the error location. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 `<head>` elements on your page:

```
<head>
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>` declarations. This declaration should only appear once and should be the first thing in your `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `rel` attribute and `type` attributes in the link tag used to include the css file.

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Everything is there. I really think IE is being bugged as I tried on a separate machine and the CSS is working for some pages but not others even though the entire site is PHP template generated. Also the background is coming up gray for the body even though nothign is in the CSS to be causing that.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a [Doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I have a doctype in there <!DOCTYPE... for some reason the stack code isnt putting it in :P

Comment: Oh ok. Just wanted to make sure you weren't missing one of the most important elements.

Comment: Could you try adding your Doctype declaration to the code again? I can assure you it is possible, and it might help us troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a head tag inside your head tag, right before the link tag. Remove that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, css rules only apply to documents listed as `text/html`

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#css

Could this be the issue?

Comment: Im gonna try changing up the doc types as you suggest see if that helps.